# HP PSC 1410 all scanner's images are black

Tags: printer, scanner

I have a HP PSC 1410 printer with scanner inside.

I've been scanning documents and images with it for the last couple of years.

Recently my scanner has stopped performing as excepted and i can't scan or copy images\documents.

My problem is that every images\document i'm trying to scan - the result from the printer is a black page.

I've been googling about this issue and couldn't find any helpful stuff beside replacing the whole printer - which is something i'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas ? I've read something about the shipping lock of the scanner but couldn't find any information about how to check it..

Comment: This is off-topic, but it sounds like either the light-source (bulb) or the photocell (image pickup) is U/S. The scanner believes the image to be completely dark: no light is being picked up.

Comment: You should ask the support of your printer for help.

Comment: Usually the scanner is a "light wand" which runs along with a "scan wand", and the page is scanned slowly across the page. Run a scan with the lid open and nothing on the platten so that you can examine the scanning mechanism.

Comment: @horatio scanning mechanism looks ok... there is a scanning light

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Uninstall HP Software (From cd)

Before performing below steps please unplug the USB cable or disconnect the network connection from printer.

a. Insert the cd into the cd drive then go to my computer

b. Right click on cd drive select explore

c. Click on util then open CCC file

d. Double click on “Uninstall_L3.bat” and then press enter in command window and follow the instruction

e. Restart the computer

Step 2:Reinstall HP software

Please visit this link for your solution. This may help you

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Scanning-Faxing-and-Copying/HP-PSC-1510-scans-copies-black-pages/td-p/78420

Comment: So your advice is to uninstall the HP software?  Where's Steps 2+? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. This is how it began, the software was showing me warnings that the cartridges needed alignment, so I printed the test page, but the black ink was very low and the test page was printed with a bad quality, but I assumed it was going to work anyway.

So following the instructions I put the test page on the scanner and scanned the bad test page. After 2 or 3 scanned documents they started to come partially black (like 90% of the page) black, and then all black.

What I did was to change the black ink cartridge and printed a good quality test page and made the alignment properly.

The first scan was not black, but the image was incomplete but not black anymore. I made an alignment test again. I closed the HP software, turned off the printer, then on, then opened the HP software, scanned a document and voila! It was good again.

Maybe it does not apply for everyone, but in my case it worked.